# C# Refresh a Form by Button Press(on the same form) to show Initial Control Values

Tags: winforms, refresh, reload

EDIT:  VERSION:   4.0.30319.42000

I'm trying to find the easiest way around this.

I have ONE form with multiple control types.
Before the form loads, I have a routine to load the form's controls' values from a settings file.
I then call the form open using Application.Run
This works fine.

I have an on_change routine that knows when any form's controls' value changes and shows a CANCEL button.

I would like to be able to have the user press this CANCEL button and revert back to the forms ORIGINAL values for each control (in below code example, MY BOX).  WITHOUT closing the form (and losing visibility of it).

I'd like to not have to reload the form all over again.  I was hoping there was something I could do with FormState, but I'm unsure how that would work.

Some sample code below:

```
public class Settings
{
     public static string MYPathFile_M = "";
}

public class MYClass
{
     [STAThread]
     public void main()
     {
          if(!fileExists())  //  Verifies setting file exists and reads in to variables
          {
               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
               Application.Run(new MYFORM_FORM());
          }
     }

     public bool fileExists()  // SIMPLIFIED FOR SPACE...
     {
          // if(!File.Exists ....
          // Open and read settings file
          // Load settings from file into public class Settings variables
          return true;
     }
}

public class MYFORM_FORM : Form
{
     public string result = null;

     public MYFORM_FORM()
     {
          // MY FORM SETTINGS
          this.ClientSize = new Size(1452, 577);
          this.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
          this.Margin = new Padding(2, 4, 2, 4);
          this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
          this.MaximizeBox = false;
          this.MinimizeBox = false;
          this.ControlBox = false;
          this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
          this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
          this.MaximumSize = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
          int FontSize = 12;
          int ControlSpacing = 15;
          this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler((sender, e) => MYFORM_FORM_FormClosing(sender, e));
          this.Load += new System.EventHandler((sender, e) => MYFORM_FORM_Load(sender, e));
          this.Name = "MYFORM_FORM";
          this.Text = "My Form Settings"; 

          // MY BOX SETTINGS
          RichTextBox MYBox = new RichTextBox();
          MYBox.Location = new Point(12, 313);
          MYBox.Name = "MYBox";
          MYBox.ReadOnly = false;
          MYBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
          MYBox.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
          MYBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(938, 56);
          MYBox.TabIndex = 10;
          MYBox.Text = Settings.MYPathFile_M;  // Is a file path variable from public class Settings
          this.Controls.Add(MYBox);
          MYBox.BringToFront();

          // MY CANCEL BUTTON SETTINGS
          Button Cancel_Button = new Button();
          Cancel_Button.AutoEllipsis = true;
          Cancel_Button.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
          Cancel_Button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
          Cancel_Button.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
          Cancel_Button.Location = new Point(1035, 517);
          Cancel_Button.Name = "Cancel_Button";
          Cancel_Button.Text = "CANCEL";
          Cancel_Button.Size = new Size(200, 48);
          Cancel_Button.Visible = false;  // Will be made true when there's a change on the form
          Cancel_Button.TabIndex = 20;
          Cancel_Button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
          Cancel_Button.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Cancel_Button_Clicked(sender, e));
          this.Controls.Add(Cancel_Button);

          Functions.ShowForm(this);
     }
     
     private void Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if(Global.SaveChanges)  // Returns TRUE if there were changes on the form
          {
               DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to cancel changes?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
               switch(dr)
               {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                    this.Controls["Cancel_Button"].Visible = false;
                    //  WHAT CODE COULD BE PLACED HERE TO ACCOMPLISH WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO??  //
                    //  FORM ORIGINAL VALUES SHOULD BE REINSTATED AND CANCEL BUTTON DISAPPEARS //
                    break;
                    case DialogResult.No:
                    break;
               }
     }
     else { this.Close(); }
     }
}

public class Functions
{
     public static void ShowForm(Form f)
     {
          IntPtr myHandle = f.Handle;
          SetForegroundWindow(myHandle.ToInt32());
     }

     [DllImport("User32.dll")]
     public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
}
```

Hoping something relatively simple could be placed in the Cancel Button routine to be able to revert the form's controls to the initial values that were loaded in at the start.

Not sure best way to do that.

Comment: How did you come up with this weird code? Don't you have Visual Studio (or other IDE) to help you with the design? It's much simpler, for example, use the standard Settings and (eventually) data bindings. Project Settings also allow to reset to default values when needed. You can also handle multiple Settings, e.g., one for general use and others for some specialized purpose. No need to have static or *Global* stuff around

Comment: It's just a sample and it's running within a container where I can't define namespace. Plus I'm not an all knowing omnipotent coder.. So any positive suggestions within the sample code will be appreciated

Comment: I don't really know what that means, some more details on your context could be useful. Anyway, you can persist Settings that are created when the application is run and pass to the Form a copy of these Settings. When you need to reset, use the persisted copy to restore *default* values. You can pass a copy of the Settings class in the Form Constructor

Comment: Appreciate that.  Any 'code' examples you could pass my way about what you're talking about would be helpful.  I've spent hours trying to find/understand what/how to do what I want and this place kinda was my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm using nullables here, as in:

```
public static Settings? defaultSettings = null;
```

If your .NET version doesn't support this feature, remove `?` from the declarations.
Not the Null-Conditional Operator (it exists since C# 6), as in:

```
settings = MYClass.defaultSettings?.Clone();
```

---

Change the Settings class, so it uses properties instead of Fields.
Add a method (named `Clone()` here) that generates a new object using the stored values:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string MYPathFile_M { get; set; } = "";
    // Other Properties

    public Settings Clone() {
        // Generates a new Settings object with stored values
        return new Settings() {
            MYPathFile_M = this.MYPathFile_M
        };
    }
}
```

In your main class, assign the values you get from your file.
Note that in your code, you have `if(!fileExists()) { }`, which doesn't make much sense

```
public class MYClass
{
    public static Settings? defaultSettings = null; 

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      if(fileExists()) {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.Run(new MYFORM_FORM(defaultSettings.Clone()));
      }
        public bool fileExists()
        {
            // [...]
            defaultSettings = new Settings {
                MYPathFile_M = "Some value from file",
                // Other Properties
            };
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In your Form, add a Constructor that accepts a Settings object.
This Constructor calls the default Constructor, which is responsible for the initialization of the interface.

The `InitializeSettingsBindings()` method then binds properties of Controls to the Properties of the `Settings` class object. When you change the values of a bound property in the UI, the value of the corresponding property of the Settings object is updated accordingly:

```
public class MYFORM_FORM : Form {

    private Settings? settings = null;
    private BindingSource? settingsSource = null;

    public MYFORM_FORM() {
        // [Your current initialization];
        // Remove MYBox.Text = Settings.MYPathFile_M;, not used here
    }

    internal MYFORM_FORM(Settings initialSettings) : this() {
        settings = initialSettings;
        if (settings != null) {
            settingsSource = new BindingSource(settings, null);
            InitializeSettingsBindings();
        }
    }

    // Initialize the Controls' bindings
    private void InitializeSettingsBindings() {
        MYBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", settingsSource, nameof(settings.MYPathFile_M), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);

        // You could also use InitializeSettingsBindings() to just set    
        // Properties of Controls directly. Then call this method again when needed
        // MYBox.Text = settings.MYPathFile_M;
    }
}
```

You Cancel Button just resets the Bindings to a copy of the original values you have stored in `MYClass`.
Note that the event handler you have set in the Form initialization doesn't match the signature of the `Cancel_Button_Clicked()` method. Using a matching one here.

```
 private void Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if(Global.SaveChanges) {
           if (MessageBox.Show("Cancel changes?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
               settings = MYClass.defaultSettings?.Clone();
               if (settingsSource != null) settingsSource.DataSource = settings;
           }
      }
      else { Close(); }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  this is A LOT to chew on.  And honestly, I was hoping to avoid doing something like this if at all possible.  I was thinking if there was simply just some way to reload the whole form instance when hitting the cancel button, that could have been a much easier solution.
As, all the settings from the settings file are read into the public class settings variables prior to calling the form.
Thus, recalling(reloading, redrawing, refreshing or whatever) the form would just present all form controls originally set values back to the beginning.

Comment: I was indeed thinking I might just have to keep a copy of the changed controls in a parallel temp variable, and if the cancel button was clicked, then simply loop through all the fields of the public class settings variables and re-apply them to the controls.

Comment: I was reading in variables:
`code`
Type type = typeof(Settings);
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
     string name = field.Name;
     object temp = field.GetValue(null);
     string line;
     while ((line=streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
          var varline = line.Split('=');
          string VariableName = varline[0];
          string VariableValue = varline[1];
          bool result;
          if(varline[0] == name)
          { if (temp is string) { string value = VariableValue as string; field.SetValue(this, value); }
`code`

Comment: What you see here is extremely simple and automates the whole thing at the same time.  Test it and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks @Jimi.  But again, it honestly feels it'd be easier to just close and reopen the form at this point.  Will give the code a whirl...  Thanks.  If anything it's a learning experience..

Comment: Just FYI, I'm just not able to get this piece of code working and getting error for this line: `return new MySettings() { MYPathFile_M = this.MYPathFile_M };`  ERROR: `The type or namespace name 'MySettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`   This Code:
`public class Settings
{
    public string MYPathFile_M { get; set; };  // = "" removed due to invalid 'token' error

    public Settings Clone()
    {    public Settings Clone() {
         return new MySettings() { MYPathFile_M = this.MYPathFile_M }; }
    }
}`

Comment: Yep, I originally named the class object `MySettings`, then changed it to `Settings` to match yours, but forgot to change one piece, it's pretty obvious

Comment: Ok.  This generates 'does not contain constructor that takes 0 arguments.
`internal MYFORM_FORM(Settings initialSettings) : this() {`  And this next line generates 'nameof' does not exist in current context `MYBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", settingsSource, nameof(settings.MYPathFile_M), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);`
So seems I guess I have to make a `public class NameOf()`  and within `public static String nameof<T>(Expression<Func<T>> name)`  ???  Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: 1) You probably have removed the parameter-less Constructor (`public MYFORM_FORM() { }`) 2) Just use the property name (`"MYPathFile_M"`)

Comment: In relation to this new solution being suggested, previously I was looping through all variables in the `public class Settings` and assigning the variable found by the matching field name from the settings file to value by `field.SetValue(this, value)`. Now as this has been switch to a 'Property' I'm at a loss on how to take this previous example statement and make it work with this new solution:  `Settings.MYPathFile.Trim().ToLower()`  This is now yielding error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Settings.MYPathFile.get'"  [cont]...

Comment: So I can no longer simply say something like:
`if(Settings.MYPathFile_M != f.Controls["MYBox"].Text.ToString())`
And wondering how to assign the text file variable value to the found variable within the newly defined `public class Settings` .
Meaning I still want to loop through all Variable Tags within the `public class Settings' property.  But it's now redefined and has { get; set; } and this is a totally new approach I'm not familiar with.

Comment: The problem is, I need to pass a dynamic object to the FORM and it causes the `MYFORM_FORM does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`.  Thus my call line is changed to:  `Application.Run(new MYFORM_FORM(defaultSettings.Clone(), MY));`  And then: `internal MYFORM_FORM(Settings initialSettings, dynamic MY) : this()`  and then `public MYFORM_FORM(dynamic MY)`
But I can't think rightly about how to resolve this as I still need to pass the dynamic object VA to the form in and around the code example you provided.  Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

@jimi

Yeah, it's Net framework 4.8 and won't support nullables.
Kinda stuck on on this, as getting "**Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration**"  in the first line below.

I'm also not following how MySettings() is being used.

Admittedly some of the concepts you're using are still beyond my experience.

```
public class Settings
{
    public string MYPathFile_M { get; set; } = ""; // File Path/Executable
    //public bool MYTrack { get; set; } = false; // User Track Boolean
    //public int MYNUM { get; set; } = 0; // Display Info Number
    
    public Settings Clone()   // Generates a new Settings object with stored values
    { return new MySettings() { MYPathFile_M = this.MYPathFile_M };
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer which is actually a request of clarification. Just ask using comments -- That kind of initialization requires C# 6+. IMO, you shouldn't use an older version of the language. If you have to, just remove the assignment: `= "";` from the property declaration

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't know how to cleanly show code within a comment.
Yeah, I have no choice about the .net framework version.  It's an inline function within another application.

Comment: That's not about the .NET Framework version, it's about the C# Language version. If you can target .NET 4.8, then you can use up to C# 7.3. Unless you have other restrictions, but this information must be part of the question

Comment: Thanks for your help, but however appropriate your idea/solution is, it's too beyond my understanding to really implement it.  I'm also constrained by .net framework 4.8 and no control over namespaces.
The SIMPLIST way at this point is just to somehow RELOAD the form with the original values from 'public class Settings'.  On the 'changed' event for each control on the form, I'll just take that value and assign to 'public class C_Settings' variable.  If the user chooses to save the settings, it will use those to write to the file.. I would like to try your way, but I'm also ..[cont...]

Comment: ...[cont] relying on reading the file variables by looping through the field.name of `public class Settings` and finding the match within the settings file and then pulling and assigning the value to the variable that way.  It's ugly I guess, but I can just have a duplicate `public class C_Settings` for a copy of the variables that would be used for writing to the file (the changed values from the form).
So at this point, I just need to find a way to refresh/reload the form.  By doing that, it'll load back in the `public class Settings` variables.  Could you help?

Comment: @Jimi  Right.  Apologies:  Version returned is:  4.0.30319.42000

Comment: DAMN, that's old! Maybe you can specify a more recent version. Anyway, that code is pretty much *standard*, just remove all `?`, check for `null` explicitly and assign the values of Properties in the class Constructor only

Answer (score 0):

So I've since revisited this code and have decided to handle things differently and provided another possible answer.

I've kept the Settings class the same to use fields.
Instead, I've added a Dictionary for the controls on the form and will reload the original values (unchanged) if the user wishes to Cancel changes (Via Cancel Button).  The Cancel Button event will load back in the original dictionary values and repopulate the form field's with those values.
So far things seem to work OK.  This covers Textboxes, Checkboxes and Comboboxes.

In the FORM:

```
public class MYFORM : Form {

     private Dictionary<Control, object> originalValues = new Dictionary<Control, object>();  // Add this to set up your dictionary

     public MYFORM() {
          [...]
     }  

     // Add Dictionary routing to the form's load event
     private void MYFORM_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
          // Create dictionary of all original values in order to recall upon a cancel
          foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
          {
          if (control is TextBox) { originalValues.Add(control, control.Text); }
          else if (control is CheckBox) { originalValues.Add(control, ((CheckBox)control).Checked); }
          else if (control is ComboBox) { originalValues.Add(control, ((ComboBox)control).SelectedIndex); }
          }
     }

     // Add the recall of original values via the Dictionary into the form.
     private void Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
          {
          if (control is TextBox) { control.Text = originalValues[control].ToString(); }
          else if (control is CheckBox) { ((CheckBox)control).Checked = (bool)originalValues[control]; }
          else if (control is ComboBox) { ((ComboBox)control).SelectedIndex = (int)originalValues[control]; }
          }
     }
}
```